# AspectJ Pointcut - addressing to Button addClickListener

Tags: java, vaadin, aspectj

I'm not sure if you allowed using AspectJ in such a way, therefore I'm giving it a try here to find out if it's possible or it's just the false usage of AspectJ.

Also, I have many Buttons in different Forms named `btnSave` and I want to run a function, which takes place in my AspectJ file, every time I call `btnSave.addClickListener()`, but it's somehow impossible to address the pointcut to a component's method.

I have tried something like this,

```
pointcut checkIfClicked(): execution(void com.example.AspectJ_Test.*.addClickListener(..));

void around():checkIfClicked(){
    try{
        System.out.println("Button has been clicked!");
    }catch(Exception ex){

    }

}
```

I also thought of creating an extra function for buttons and calling those functions, but I'm interested to know if it's possible this way.

Please tell me if it's not clear what I exactly mean.

By the way, I'm trying to address a Vaadin Button addClickListener().

Best regards.

Comment: addClickListener is not executed when the button is clicked. The actionPerform is

Comment: Thanks, @Stultuske. So I searched again on the internet and checked some results, which brought me to the point that, what I am trying to do is not a cross-cutting concern and maybe I shouldn't do that ^^. But I'm still curious if it's possible to do.

Comment: so, for starters: don't link your pointcut to the addClickListener. it's the method inside the ClickListener interface you should be checking

Comment: I've tried that already and get this warning all the time ´Xlint:adviceDidNotMatch´

Comment: Reza, please edit your question, turning it into a full [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). AOP is about weaving a cross-cutting concern into an apllication. I need to see both the aspect and the application in order to run both and help you fix it. But the MCVE rule applies to all questions on SO, otherwise you will just get speculative answers and not the help you hope for.  Thank you.